# Path that gets within given distance of each point in order

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, euclidean-distance, plane

I have an ordered list of points in a 2D plane. I'd like to find the shortest route such that it gets at least within distance X (or closer) from each point, in the given order. How do I find this route?

I realize that the points that will determine the route (the direction changes there) will lie on circles of perimeter X, centered on the input points themselves, but I didn't get any further.

I'm implementing this in Python, but will be happy for any theoretical help.

Example: (oops I can't count so skipped 7)
[image: Example]

Comment: This is a generalisation of the Travelling Salesman Problem, so I'd start there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @kaya3 This is not the TSP - the points have a given order

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question , it seems to be a specific case of BFS .

Comment: @Mouse I edited the question to add an approximate, hand-made example. I don't understand how BFS would be related

Comment: Is a approximation allowed? It feels the points depend on each other, but the dependency effect fades away quickly after 2-3 hops...

Comment: @user3184950 for my purposes it's ok. I've been thinking about it and always ended up on mutual dependencies too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps there's an analytical approach, but this problem certainly can be solved with convex programming. Here's a Python implementation with cvxpy that outputs EPS.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np


def objective(points):
    return np.sum(np.linalg.norm(points[1:] - points[:-1]))


def shortest_path(x, centers):
    points = cp.reshape(cp.Variable(centers.size), centers.shape)
    cost = cp.sum(cp.norm(points[1:] - points[:-1], axis=1))
    constraints = []
    for i, center in enumerate(centers):
        constraints.append(cp.SOC(x, points[i] - center))
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost), constraints)
    prob.solve()
    return points.value


def main():
    x = 0.05
    centers = np.random.random_sample((10, 2))
    points = shortest_path(x, centers)
    print("%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0")
    print("%%BoundingBox:0 0 504 504")
    print("72 dup translate")
    print("360 dup scale")
    print("0 setlinewidth")
    for center in centers:
        print(*center, x, 0, 360, "arc")
        print("stroke")
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        print(*point, "lineto" if i else "moveto")
    print("stroke")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to find minimum distance to the point which is x minimux x points away from the next point in the route.

I would suggesting finding the shortest distance between the starting point and all the circles cirumfrence , then choosing the shortest value and again repeating the same step.

So it will be like .

you have 4 points and you start at point 1(starting point which is at the cicumfrence of the circle 1),

calculate the shortest distance using [shortest distance formula from cirumfrence](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-circle)

for the rest of the 3 circles (The distance will be calculated from point 1 to the circumfrence of all 3 circles ) and after that select the minimum distance from three.

Now move to point two (the one has the shortest distance) and repeat same for other two points left.

```
circle1(x0,y0)
circle2(xx0,yy0)
circle3(xxx0,yyy0)
circle4(xxxx0,yyyy0)

cirle 1 (x0,y0) is the center and you have **p1** on circumfrence p1(x1,y1) 

from p1 calculate the shortest distance to all three circles like 
distance from p1 to circle2 
Distp1Toc2= sqrt(square(x1-xx0) + square(y1-yy0) -r) // this will give you shortest distance from point 1 to a point on circle2 cirumfrence 

repeat this for circle3 and cirlce4 to calculate **Dist_p1_To_c3** and **Dist_p1_To_c4**  then select the minimum distance

lets consider **Dist_p1_To_c2** is minimum and now from the point Dist_p1_To_c2 again calculate the distance to circle 3 and circle4 to find minimum distance.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. But I feel like you're always looking for the closest point, but that's incorrect. The points have pre-determined order, I just don't want to pass directly through them, but "cut the corners" making use of that I only need to get within given distance of that point, not go directly through it

Comment: nope , it's not looking at the closest point but the closest point on the cirumfrence of a circle drawn with the points.  Note that the formula works whether P is inside or outside the circle.